# How to use a variable to represent a mathematical symbol in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

How to use a mathematical symbol as a variable for a mathematical operation in Javascript?

Works:

```
if(1 < 2) alert("yes");
```

Fails:

```
var sign = "<";
if(1 sign 2) alert("yes");
```

Comment: Do you want to represent the *symbol* or the *operation*?

Comment: my guess is, the var to represent the symbol to use it in an operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
if(eval('1' + sign + '2')) alert("yes");
```

But eval is frowned upon for many good reasons, so as an alternative, you could check the sign and perform the relevant test. For example:

```
if(test(1, 2, sign)) alert("yes");

function test(x, y, sign){
  switch (sign) {
    case "<":
      return x < y;
    case ">":
      return x > y;
    case "==":
      return x == y;
    // Add a case for each sign you wish to support
  }
  return false;
}
```